# Mapview marker in center not above

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mapview

[image: How to place blue marker in the center?]

I've tried `position: absolute`, can move down, but its hiding anyway in half, below the center doesn't show marker.

how to move it down to the center view?

Answer (score 1):

Find solution anchor={{ x: 0.5, y: 0.5 }}